# Tensorflow how to get history of all custom loss functions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

In the keras tutorial https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html, the section Variational autoencoder (VAE) has defined losses - `reconstruction_loss`, `kl_loss` and their sum  `vae_loss`. However, history if `fit()` can only show `vae_loss` . Is there any way to get history of other two losses as well?

Comment: I would suggest to follow this guide https://keras.io/examples/generative/vae/